# How to dual boot Windows 10 and (Kali) Linux?

Tags: linux, boot, multi-boot, windows-10, kali-linux

I tried to install (Kali) Linux over a live usb stick (live .. > Application > System Tools > Install Kali Linux), but the with Windows 10 created partition of ~60GB won't be recognized by the installer *(sda in picture 2)*.

As I said, I'm using Windows 10 as primary system. Why does the installer don't recognize my created partition?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue following these steps;

-load into the Live environment of Kali, 
-start up the Applications->Systemtools->Administration->GParted partitioning tool from the menu

ignore the error about the gpt: this is probably why you have this problem in the first place..

-remove all partitions, then, in the menu 'Device'  choose ' Create partition table and create an MS-DOS partition table.

-Create the appropriate linux partitions at the end of the disk: make sure you keep enough room at the start of the disk for the windows install.

If you're not sure about the partitions, here's good reading:
 http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/35676/how-to-choose-a-partition-scheme-for-your-linux-pc/

Now apply the changes in Gparted, reboot the machine into the Windows10 installation -media.
Setup Windows in the free space, after that, boot into the kali -setup

Kali will now recognize the windows installation as a vista install..

You should be able to follow the setup wizard from there.

Comment: Well.. Yes that should have fixed it, but as I opened gparted the first time I tried to "fix" the gpt error and followed this [guide](http://askubuntu.com/a/473073). Now I can't follow your insteuctions.. I'm getting an ntfs error in gparted. Cluster problems?..

Comment: could you post the error?

Comment: My Lenovo crashed this week and I can't reproduce the error. Please wait until its repaired (2-3 weeks).