# How do I uninstall Ubuntu 16.04 LTS in a triple booted (with Windows 10 and Kali Linux 2) and reinstall it?

Tags: ubuntu, windows-10, kali-linux

I have recently installed Ubuntu 16.04 alongside Windows 10 and Kali Linux 2. I have messed up a bit of Ubuntu by unpacking a lot of .deb files and now having problems with unmet dependencies, and I need to add more disk space to Ubuntu file system. How do I uninstall it safely, and reinstall it back after adding more free space for Ubuntu?
The Grub of Ubuntu has overwritten Kali's Grub. I assume, formatting the Ubuntu partition will wipe out Ubuntu but not the Grub which will probably have Ubuntu's entry too.

How do I do it safely without messing things up even more?

Comment: Just install Ubuntu on the same partition it already exists on.

Comment: thanks! But I need to fix the disk space and increase it @Ramhound

Comment: You might have to repair the boot loader (Grub, Windows,ect) but that is to be expected due to operating systems your installing.

Comment: Yes. So I will fix that when I am installing but, what about the disk space?

Comment: increase the size of the partition?  Your making it out to be way to complicate to simply install Ubuntu again.  [Related](http://superuser.com/questions/948856/how-to-dual-boot-windows-10-and-kali-linux?rq=1)

Comment: I need to increase more space for Ubuntu. Then install it. I am having problems doing that.

Comment: You don't really specify what your problem are.

Comment: My problem is "uninstalling ubuntu> increasing space for Ubuntu> install ubuntu". @Ramhound